# Is it a bad idea to make a swap partition on a SSD?

Tags: linux, swap

Since it has limited amount of read/write cycles, it seems to be a bad choice but I have no solid reasoning on why or why not to use it other than that.

Comment: I would actually consider getting a very small SSD (no more than 64 GB) separate from the system volume for that purpose. It would improve swap performance without the risk of wearing out the system volume. This is for Windows but might be relevant to you: http://superuser.com/questions/857750/optimal-location-of-pagefile-on-a-system-with-two-ssds-with-system-drive-faster

Comment: I think you wil lnever produce enough write operations to wear out a SSD. Look at this report ==> http://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead In addition, the swap partition will probably have very little usage unless you have a really small RAM.